Smallest eigenvalue of $A^T D^{-1} A + D$ for positive diagonal $D$.
I am wondering whether or not there exists a way to analyze the eigenvalues of
$$A^T D^{-1} A + D$$
for a square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and positive diagonal matrix $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, that, given the special structure involving $D$, provides a better lower bound than Courant-Fischer:
$$ \lambda_k \left(A^T D^{-1} A + D \right) \geq \lambda_{k} \left(A^T D^{-1} A  \right) +  \lambda_{\min} \left(D \right)$$
My hope is that one might be able to show
$$ \lambda_k \left(A^T D^{-1} A + D \right) \geq \lambda_{k} \left(A^T D^{-1} A  \right) +  \lambda_{k} \left(D \right)$$
but this seems overly-optimistic. However, the bound for the smallest eigenvalue
$$ \lambda_{\min} \left(A^T D^{-1} A + D \right) \geq \lambda_{\min} \left(A^T D^{-1} A  \right) +  \lambda_{\min} \left(D \right)$$
seems too loose. Is there any avenue to tighten this bound, say if $A^T D^{-1} A$ is positive definite rather than positive semidefinite? Or, is there simply no hope for a sharper bound?

Is there any reason to believe that $\lambda_k(A^TD^{-1} A)$ is related in any way to $\lambda_k(D)$? I think these are only related if the corresponding eigenspaces are the same, i.e., $A$ and $D$ commute which is very restrictive

Take $A = D^{1/2} B$. Then you get $B^TB + D$, so a diagonal plus any PSD matrix. aka, there is no structure to exploit here

Also ALL bounds are sharp. There are easy examples with $A$ diagonal in which all bounds hold with the $=$
